# JIRA, How to delete account by myself

Tags: jira, account

I would like to delete my account by myself.

I tried to find the menu or option in JIRA web, but I could not find.

Does anyone know how to delete my account by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting account is not a recommended way and also you can't delete your own account. You need to ask another user with JIRA Administrator privilage to remove it. Take a look at [document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/create-edit-or-remove-a-user-861253174.html) for further information.

Comment: It is possible.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit update here
Follow the link to to deactivate your account
[Delete your Atlasian account](https://id.atlassian.com/manage/close-account)